# Analysing and mapping intersection of layers with one layer with overlapping Polygons

Tags: qgis, reports, ppygis

I have one layer (a_layer) with approx 400 overlapping polygons and no more data as the fid. I want to analyse how many countys (b_layer) are coverd by each polygon of tha a_layer.

I was thinking to do that with the report builder of QGIS.

How to do that with python scripts and/or modeler in QGIS?

How to fit this in report builder?

Answer (score 1):

Install the plugin "refFunctions." This gives you access to the intersecting_geom_count() function.

Use the Field Calculator to add a numerical field to "a_layer", using this expression:

> intersecting_geom_count( 'b_layer')

[image]

Now you have a field that tells you how many counties each polygon intersects.

You can use this field for many things, for example:

Label the polygon layer with the county count field

[image]

Apply a graduated style based on the county count field

[image]

Comment: Very good workflow. Thanks. Now I want to filter each polygon and show it in the map. That's necessary beceause they overlap each other. How to do that in QGIS?

Comment: The atlas generator might be a good tool to look into. If you have questions about that, you should post a new question. https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/training_manual/forestry/forest_maps.html